# Can a signer have no interaction with a document?

Tags: docusignapi

This is thru the Rest Api. Suppose you have a signer and a document with a few signing tabs. I'm using a composite template and the signer has a template role. Suppose the template role does not match up, so the signing tabs aren't created. What you get is the left tools pane and the user can drop/drop signatures. My question: if no tabs can be created, is it possible to stop the left tool pane from showing up, that the person is basically just viewing the document? This situation may never happen, but I'd like to know if there is a way out if it does. I'm sure the answer is to prevent it from happening in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DocuSign, recipients who are assigned the "Signer" role will always be given the opportunity to provide input -- either via tabs that you've assigned to them in the document(s) or via tabs that they place on the document(s) themselves (if you assign no tabs to them). If you specify a recipient as a "Signer" but include no tabs for them, they will get the "freeform" signing experience that you describe, where they can drag/drop tabs from the left panel onto the document(s) where ever they choose -- I don't believe there's any way to prevent this.

Comment: I figured it would work like that. Setting someone as a signer means that they have an active part in the document, even if there is no specific signing tab(s) given to them. Thank you for the info.

Comment: What about using a recipient type of [CertifiedDelivery](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/#certifiedDeliveries) ? :
"Use this type if the recipient must receive the completed documents for the envelope to be completed, but the recipient does not need to sign, initial, date or add information to any of the documents. "